# Post data must be key value pair? If not how to read raw data in .Net

Tags: asp.net, post

I don't think it have to be in pairs, so if I send a plain text like below:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

httpClient.PostAsync("http://hey.com", 
new StringContent("simple string, no key value pair."));
```

Then the FormCollection below doesn't seem to offer a way to read that..

```
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection collection){

    //how to get the string I sent from collection?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FormCollection` object is a Key Value pair collection. If you are sending a simple string over then the collection will be empty unless it is formatted as a Key\Value pair.

This can be done in multiple ways.

**Option 1:** Send Key Value Pairs, where the `FormCollection` will read your string with the key `myString`:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("mystring", "My String Value")
});
httpClient.PostAsync("http://myUrl.com", content);
```

**Option 2:** Read the contents directly from the Request. This reads the raw `Request.InputStream` into a `StreamReader` into a string

```
public ActionResult ReadInput()
{
    this.Request.InputStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
    string myString = "";
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(this.Request.InputStream))
    {
        myString = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

There are many more options but either of these methods should do the trick